# What are the advantages of using "_()" in fprintf?

Tags: c, printf, gnu, gettext

I bumped into the following code in GNU Binutils:

```
......
fprintf (stream, _("Usage: %s [option(s)] [file(s)]\n"), program_name);
......
```

What's the benefit of using `_()` compared to not using it:

```
......
fprintf (stream, "Usage: %s [option(s)] [file(s)]\n", program_name);
......
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Mark-Keywords.html#Mark-Keywords

Comment: It is defined like this: `#define _(String) dgettext (PACKAGE, String)`

Comment: gettext gives your app localization so the string returned by _() could be in a different language.  Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext